# Where to cache : Database cache or App server using SessionScoped managed beans?

Tags: java, session, caching, jsf

I am building web app using **Casssandra DB** & Java with **JSF 2.0**.

Cassandra has its own caching layer and also I can cache using `SessionsScoped` managed beans in JSF. I would like to know what would be a good way to implement caching of data of different kinds: the to-be-cached data is sometimes quite big in size for 1 kind and sometimes it is small sized(2nd kind).

Since the cached data columns in Cassandra row would store the data in serialized format & with entire column structure, I guess I would be better storing them at the app server in session scoped beans whereby I can also have a better control of the cached data & cached data could be the most relevant and I guess it makes no difference in terms of the hardware requirements in the 2 cases:- (1) when I implement it using sessionscoped beans (2) if I use the DB cache.

Please list any differences in the benefits that may be there with these two caching implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not (ab)use the session scope as cache for large datasets. You're basically duplicating the cache for every visitor. You should have a single cache. The DB cache is perfectly fine.

As to the size of the data, you should effectively have a request or view scoped bean which contains *exactly* the data the enduser needs to know about in the particular request. E.g. when you're displaying a dataset of 1000 objects through pagination with 10 objects per page, then the request scoped bean should contain exactly those 10 objects and the remnant should be kept there in the DB/DB cache. The code should also be written that way that it retrievs exactly those 10 objects (and thus don't retrieve 1000 objects and then filter the desired 10 out of it).

Comment: what if the data cached in session beans is very specific to the user ?

Comment: Store *just* exactly those parameters for which the same dataset can be obtained in the request or session scope, e.g. search query, firstrow, rowcount, etc (and thus not the whole dataset itself).

Comment: I was trying to store some Ids of posts(on a social application) from his followies that should be made visible on his page. Since Ids list would be just 8 byte longs list of around 20-30 elements does that make sense to store in session bean. This is very specific as well as doesnt contain the actual dataset

Comment: I don't quite understand the functional requirement. First answer this: why is a request or view scoped bean insufficient?

Comment: I wanted to cache that list along with other lists of similar type so that it could be accessed without deserializing( otherwise caching at DB layer would contain serialized data & much bigger structure in memory ie, entire column structre rather than just column value. Each Cassandra column consists of name, value & timestamp. While the only thing I would need to store in cache is the value only). And apart from that, the cache implemented through session scoped beans would consume less memory, less work since no deserializing each time.

Comment: Request/view scoped doesnt seem to work as I wont be able to cache data in between the page refreshes unless with DB cache.

Comment: If the data is specific to the logged-in user and is been used on **every** logged-in pageview, then it's reasonable to store it along the logged-in user in the session. But for example search results and/or overviews of anything (e.g. posts, replies, comments, friends of other users, etc), should not be stored in the session scope. Stresstest eventually with 1000 concurrent users and measure.